# бесконечно работает цикл for

Tags: c#

Логика такая: я конекчусь к серверу, ввожу количество чисел для передачи и циклом `for`  передаю числа на сервер.Ошибка в том, что при `i=0` цикл срабатывает без ввода числа и `i` инкримируется бесконечно.

```
 while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Skok chisel");
            int kol = Console.Read();

            for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter {0} element", i);
                string message = Console.ReadLine();

                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                socket.Send(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine("отправилось!");
            }


        }
```

Comment: Бесконечно у вас здесь: `while (true)`, а `Console.Read()` делает не то что вы предполагаете

Comment: Попробуйте int kol = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());